# Webpage looks correct localy but not on IIS (Internet Explorer 11)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-11

When I start my project localy on my computer, and open the page in Internet Explorer 11, It looks great:

[image]

However, when I deploy the page to an IIS-server and navigate to the page, it looks like this in Internet Explorer:

[image]

Why does It differ? I don't want the user to hit F12 and change the Document Mode.

I have also tried to add meta-tags in the layout-file, but that don't work.

Here is a screen capture on the css from the page the is working correctly:
[image]

Herer Is the same but from the page that don't work:
[image]

Comment: do you see any user agent stylesheets overriding your css?

Comment: @Keith: How can I see that?

Comment: look in developer tools, each browser has its own set of style sheets, is there a style that is overriding yours? ( it will say user agent stylesheet )

Comment: @Keith: No, it's just my css-files.

Comment: ok do this, inspect one of the elements and highlight it, take a screen capture of the css in the developer tools on your local, then select the same element in the IIS-server page and in developer tools, take another screen capture, show it here so i can see what the difference is. Something is getting overridden

Comment: @Keith: Check the updated question.

Comment: Clear cache or cokie might help you..or do as Keith suggested..this seems the only way..

Comment: quickly looking at this, it seems that your local is using media queries whereas the IIS is not accepting them. Maybe its because of a different screen size

Comment: @Keith: Im using the same screen..

Comment: in your IIS, it looks like its set to IE5 in your emulation, which would not be able to handle media queries

Comment: @Keith: Yes, but why does Is It set to IE5 when I deploy to the IIS? When open via IIE Express, It Is set to 11.

Comment: that i dont know, its just your base setting for when you deploy

Answer (score 1):

When you say you start your project locally on your computer, I assume you mean via the debugger in Visual Studio.

In its default configuration, Visual Studio will launch your site in IIS Express (which will have the assets your site needs). When you deploy it to IIS proper you have to make sure all your assets are deployed with your site. By assets, I mean CSS, JavaScript, images, etc.

Without seeing the generated HTML, it's hard to tell what the problem is. If you load the problematic page in a browser and use the developer tools (I'm partial to Chrome myself), you shouldn't see any errors. If you do, that's probably your problem. Failing that, can you update your question to show the generated page's HTML?